# Calling a Get method in asp.net mvc from a post method in asp.net mvc webapi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the following Post method in webapi controller..

```
 [Route("api/myquery")]
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage MyQuery([FromBody] string id)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(id))
            {
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }


           return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
           // return RedirectToAction("MyReport", new { model = "abc" });
        }
```

I have the following Get method in asp.net mvc controller..

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MyReport(string model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

What I would like to do is call the Get method from the Post method on success.
'RedirectToAction' does not seem to work.. it says that:- it does not exist in the current context..

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is this in the same project? What you try is to call the method "MyReport" in the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the methods are in 2 different controllers...So basically you're trying to call the method `MyReport` in your webapi controller.

Try to call the method with your controller in which the method actual is:

```
return RedirectToAction("MyReport", "MyController", new { model = "abc" });
```

Comment: Yes, methods are in two different controllers. But, MyReport is in a mvc controller not mvc web api controller, The method myquery is in a web api controller.. and RedirectToAction does not exist in mvc webapi

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or copy the original error text? Is it a compilation error?

Comment: webapi controller does not have a  RedirectToAction Method, so how can I use it????